# google script doc to pdf resizes rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I have a document that i use as a template, url: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ng00Sw0V-3_htLF2-SyPj895g_V9bi1mKQc1LOaHPNY/edit?usp=sharing

I'm using a script when a form is submited and export it to pdf

```
function testExport() {
   var pdf = DocumentApp.openById(docTemplate).getAs("application/pdf");
  DriveApp.createFile(pdf);
};
```

But the exported link looks like https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_YrT5Ue-LAvUllyQ0ZpbkRodVU/view?usp=sharing

Size of rows between the table seems to increased and the overall quality looks bad, is there a way to fix it? When I download the doc file as pdf the then it looks really good.

Comment: I can't see in your example about changing row size, but I can see that automatic pagination is not consistent between docs and apps script PDF interface.

Comment: What do you mean by that. In my document fontsize between tables is set to 6 but in the pdf it changes to 10 or 12 and then the document overflows. It only happens when exporting with script if I download as pdf it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Document.getAs()` uses a slightly different converter then the Google Docs UI does. You can get closer by using the conversion functionality built into the Drive API, exposed in `File.exportLinks`. The sample below uses the Drive Advanced Service to do the conversion and save the result.

```
function exportAsPdf(documentId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(documentId);
  var url = file.exportLinks['application/pdf'];
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });
  var contents = response.getBlob();
  contents.setName(file.title + '.pdf');
  DriveApp.createFile(contents);
}
```